# How to fix my fstab file when I try and mount my server with spaces in the name

Tags: server, mount, fstab

I am running ubuntu 22.04 and I have the following server to mount:

```
//MARS/Students/2024/LastName, FirstName
```

I have gotten the following error after using `sudo mount -a`

mount error(22): Invalid argument
my `/etc/fstab` file line looks like:

```
//MARS/Students/2024/LastName, Firstname    /media/windowsshare   cifs  credentials=/path/to/creds,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

I have tried multiple things like:

```
//MARS/Students/2024/LastName,\040FirstName
"//MARS/Students/2024/LastName, FirstName"
\"//MARS/Students/2024/LastName, FirstName\"
\"//MARS/Students/2024/LastName,\040FirstName\"
"//MARS/Students/2024/LastName,\040FirstName"
```

None of these work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the comma and not the space (replacing with \040 should work for that). I would try googling for how to handle the comma first.

Comment: is there a comma escape code?

Comment: @MATOS "is there a comma escape code?" 040 is *octal* for the decomal number 32, and 32 is the ordinal of ASCII space. A search for "ascii table with octal" will answer all your questions.  (And tell you where %20 came from.)

Comment: Does the samba share mounts when you try from command line?

Comment: well I wanna just use sudo and fstab but I tried configuring it but it didnt work

Comment: First try to mount from command line (`sudo mount "//MARS/Students/2024/LastName, Firstname"    /media/windowsshare`). And if it works, then try to edit the `fstab` file.

Comment: Looking at `man fstab` and googling for nfs mounts leads me to suggest something like `MARS:/Students/...`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the space character (octal code 040), you should also escape the comma character (octal code 054) and any non-ASCII characters in the samba share:

```
//MARS/Students/2024/LastName\054\040FirstName    /media/windowsshare   cifs  credentials=/path/to/creds,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

For a list of ASCII octal codes see https://www.asciitable.com/

You should pay special attention whether your samba share (e.g., "first name" and "last name") contains any non-ASCII letters or symbols.

Comment: Still calls the same error

Comment: Check proper case also. Is it `Firstname` or `FirstName`?

Comment: The case ic correct in my case I checked. ```FirstName``` is just a placeholder for my name which is capitalized

Comment: I'm not certain you can escape the comma, and I'm not at a place I can test right now. If you *can* I suspect it would be by enclosing in single quotes: `'//MARS/Students/2024/LastName, FirstName'`

Comment: It raises a parse error

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer just for the formatting, but you may have to do something like this as a workaround:

/etc/fstab:

```
//MARS/Students/2024/    /media/windowsshare   cifs  credentials=/path/to/creds,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

and then

```
$ ln -s /media/windowsshare/'LastName, FirstName' ~user/windowsshare
```

relying on normal user permissions for access protections.

Comment: Aye, a symbolic link tends to fix all problems :) ... but it might add new ones.